# Oracle-XML : XMLAGG / XMLELEMENT / XMLATTRIBUTES in a SQL query to group by a specific field

Tags: sql, arrays, json, xml, aggregate

The below SQL:

```
SELECT
XMLELEMENT("classics", xmlattributes('xxxxxxxxx' AS "eventId"),             
XMLELEMENT("author",xmlattributes(FIRST_NAME AS "firstName", LAST_NAME AS "lastName", BIRTH AS "dob", DEATH AS "dod" )),
XMLELEMENT("bibliography",
XMLELEMENT("type",xmlattributes(DESCRIPTION AS "desc"),
XMLELEMENT("award", xmlattributes(NOBEL AS "nobelPrize"))),
XMLELEMENT("books",xmlattributes(BOOK_TITLE AS "title", PUBLISHED_DATE AS "published" )))) 
FROM CLASSICS 
WHERE AUTHOR_ID=23;
```

does not group by correctly by book, what i am trying to achieve is to have this XML as result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classics  eventId="234567890">
   <author firstName="Ernest " lastName="Hemingway" dob="1899-07-21" dod="1961-07-02" />
   <bibliography>
      <inner>
         <type desc="Novel" >
            <award nobel="true"  />
         </type>
         <books>
            <inner title="The Old Man And The Sea" published="1952" />
            <inner title="For Whom The Bell Tolls" published="1940" />
            <inner title="A Farewell To Arms" published="1929" />
         </books>
      </inner>
   </bibliography>
</classics>
```

at the moment i get 3 records - 3 distinct XML for each of the books - I have tried to use XMLAGG to group by AUTHOR_id (this field is the link for each book in the table CLASSICS table for an authir) - it is very simple structure  ONE AUTHOR HAS PUBLISHED AT LEAST ONE BOOK OR MANY - and i need to store the "classic" xml object for an author containing an array of books inside another array "bibliography"

this is the code i tried to used inside the XMLELEMENT "bibliography" for the Array "books":WITH NO LUCK

select 
xmlagg(
xmlelement("books",
xmlattributes(BOOK_TITLE AS "title", PUBLISHED_DATE AS "published" )
))from CLASSICS 
GROUP BY AUTHOR_ID

the main goal in the end is to reach this JSON structure after i have the XML:

```
{
   "eventId": "234567890",
   "author": {
      "firstName": "Ernest",
      "lastName": "Hemingway",
      "dob": "1899-07-21",
      "dod": "1961-07-02"
   },
   "bibliography": [
      {
         "type": {
            "desc": "Novel",
            "award": {
               "nobelPrize": "1954"
            }
         },
         "books": [
            {
               "title": "The Old Man And The Sea",
               "published": "1952"
            },
            {
               "title": "For Whom The Bell Tolls",
               "published": "1940"
            },
            {
               "title": "A Farewell To Arms",
               "published": "1929"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

but seems quiet complicated declare arrays of objects in XML/SQL.

any suggestions?

Comment: Anybody on the rescue?

Comment: I am not an oracle man... But you might search  for `XMLAGG` and `XMLFOREST` ...